# Java : Creating chunks of List for processing

Tags: java, performance, list, out-of-memory, guava

I have a list with a large number of elements. While processing this list, in some cases I want the list to be partitioned into smaller sub-lists and in some cases I want to process the entire list.

```
private void processList(List<X> entireList, int partitionSize)
{
    Iterator<X> entireListIterator = entireList.iterator();
    Iterator<List<X>> chunkOfEntireList =   Iterators.partition(entireListIterator, partitionSize);
    while (chunkOfEntireList.hasNext()) {
        doSomething(chunkOfEntireList.next());
        if (chunkOfEntireList.hasNext()) {
            doSomethingOnlyIfTheresMore();
        }
    }
```

I'm using com.google.common.collect.Iterators for creating partitions. Link of documentation [here](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#partition%28java.util.Iterator,%20int%29) 
So in cases where I want to partition the list with size 100, I call

```
processList(entireList, 100);
```

Now, when I don't want to create chunks of the list, I thought I could pass Integer.MAX_VALUE as partitionSize.

```
processList(entireList, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

But this leads to my code going out of memory. Can someone help me out? What am I missing? What is Iterators doing internally and how do I overcome this?

EDIT : I also require the "if" clause inside to do something only if there are more lists to process. i.e i require hasNext() function of the iterator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting an out of memory error because `Iterators.partition()` internally populates an array with the given partition length. The allocated array is always the partition size because the actual number of elements is not known until the iteration is complete. (The issue could have been prevented if they had used an `ArrayList` internally; I guess the designers decided that arrays would offer better performance in the common case.)

Using `Lists.partition()` will avoid the problem since it delegates to `List.subList()`, which is only a *view* of the underlying list:

```
private void processList(List<X> entireList, int partitionSize) {
    for (List<X> chunk : Lists.partition(entireList, partitionSize)) {
        doSomething(chunk);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally while partitioning it will allocate a new list with given partitionSize. So it is obvious in this case that there will be such error. Why don't you use the original list when you need only single partition. Possible solutions.

1. create a separate overloaded method where you won't take the size.
2. pass the size as -1 when you don't need any partition. In the method check the value, if -1 then put the original list into the `chunkOfEntireList`,.

Comment: I considered doing this. But it makes the code super ugly in my case. Is there an alternate solution that I can try apart from Iterators.partition() ?

Comment: you can create a partiotion method.. then in that method you can implement any of the 2 proposed solution. It shoulldn't make the code ugly